# Rendering an Object to a table using React.js syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I can't get the following to work in React's `render()`

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    ...
    { this.state.data.map( (entry, index) => 
      <tr>{ Object.values(entry).forEach( e => <td>{e}</td> )}</tr> 
    )}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, when I replace `<td>{e}</td>` with `console.log(e)` I see what I expect to render. In fact, no regular html element would render inside the `forEach` method either. What is the common way of doing this in React?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.forEach` doesn't return anything, but `.map` does.  If you change

```
Object.values(entry).forEach( e => <td>{e}</td>
```

to

```
Object.values(entry).map( e => <td>{e}</td>
```

that should work.